# Error bars in pgfplots symlog bar chart not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart, error-bars

I'm trying to create a bar graph with symlog axes and black error bars.
However, the best I got so far is below. Now my error bars disappear behind my bars and have colors that are not black for some reason.
I tried changing the order of `\addplot`, but then my legend turned blue and red instead of black and green.

How do I get my error bars black, in the front and a correct legend?

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{pythonGreen}{RGB}{0,128,0}

\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\tikzmath
{
  function symlog(\x,\a){
    \yLarge = ((\x>\a) - (\x<-\a)) * (ln(max(abs(\x/\a),1)) + 1);
    \ySmall = (\x >= -\a) * (\x <= \a) * \x / \a ;
    return \yLarge + \ySmall ;
  };
  function symexp(\y,\a){
    \xLarge = ((\y>1) - (\y<-1)) * \a * exp(abs(\y) - 1) ;
    \xSmall = (\y>=-1) * (\y<=1) * \a * \y ;
    return \xLarge + \xSmall ;
  };
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\basis{1}
    \pgfplotsset
  {
    y coord trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{symlog(#1,\basis)}\pgfmathresult},
    y coord inv trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{symexp(#1,\basis)}\pgfmathresult},
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,int detect,precision=2},
}

\pgfplotstableread{ % x, y1, y2, y_err1, y_err2
0 0.78 -1.03 0.21 1.07
1 -540 -1150 0.06 216
2 2.6 5.15 0.08 1.16
3 7.36 9.86 0.004 0.55
4 0.47 -0.03 0.75 0.76
5 -0.87 -0.87 0.99 1.06
6 0.10 -0.33 0.24 0.26
}\dataset

\begin{axis} [width=\linewidth,
    ybar = 0cm,
    bar width = 10pt,
    xtick = data,
    scaled ticks = base 10:0,
    ytick = {-10000, -1000, -100, -10, -1, 0, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000},
    scaled y ticks=false,
    minor ytick = {-9000, -8000, ..., -2000, -900, -800, ..., -200, -90, -80, ..., -20, -9, -8, ..., -2, -.9, -.8, ..., .9, 2, 3, ..., 9, 20, 30, ..., 90, 200, 300, ..., 900, 2000, 3000, ..., 9000},
    ymajorgrids,
    yminorgrids,
    xmajorgrids,
    xticklabels={A, B, C, D, E, F, G},
    x tick label style={rotate=90},
    ylabel=\tiny{Y-Value},
    tick label style={font=\tiny},
    legend style={nodes=right, font=\tiny}, 
    legend pos = south east
    ]
    
\addplot+[forget plot, mark=none, draw=black, fill=black] 
        plot[error bars/.cd, y dir=plus, y explicit]
        table[x=0, y=1, y error expr = {symlog(\thisrow{1} + \thisrow{3}, \basis) - symlog(\thisrow{1}, \basis)}]\dataset;        

\addplot+[forget plot, mark=none,xticklabels=\empty, draw=none, fill=none] 
        plot[error bars/.cd, y dir=minus, y explicit]
        table[x=0, y=1, y error expr = {symlog(\thisrow{1}, \basis) - symlog(\thisrow{1} - \thisrow{3}, \basis)}]\dataset;        
\addplot+[draw=black, fill=black!75]
        table[x index=0, y index=1] \dataset;
        

\addplot+[forget plot, mark=none, draw=none, fill=none] 
        plot[error bars/.cd, y dir=plus, y explicit]
        table[x=0,y=2,y error expr = {symlog(\thisrow{2} + \thisrow{4}, \basis) - symlog(\thisrow{2}, \basis)}]\dataset;
\addplot+[forget plot, mark=none, xticklabels=\empty, draw=none, fill=none] 
        plot[error bars/.cd, y dir=minus, y explicit]
        table[x=0,y=2,y error expr = {symlog(\thisrow{2},\basis)-symlog(\thisrow{2}-\thisrow{4},\basis)}]\dataset;    

\addplot+[draw=black, fill=pythonGreen]
        table[x index=0, y index=2] \dataset;           

\legend {data1, data2};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. I haven't looked at your code enough to understand it, but two things: 1) after `error bars/.cd` try adding `error bar style={black}` to make them black. 2) not important, but why do you do `\addplot [<some options>] plot[<other options>]`? You don't need that `plot` keyword there, that's for pure TikZ, just `\addplot[<some options>, <other options>]` should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what's going on, but I think perhaps you can simplify things quite a bit. Instead of separate plots for the error bars, do everything with one `\addplot` per dataset. You can specify `y error plus expr` and `y error minus expr` separately, in the same plot. `error bar style={black}` after `error bars/.cd` will make them black.

Other comments:

- Your `ycoord (inv) trafo` shouldn't have `\pgfmathresult` at the end. The code for those should only set `\pgfmathresult`, which `\pgfmathparse` does, not actually use it. The many warnings you got in the log about characters not being in nullfont is a result of this.
- `\tiny` is not an macro that takes an argument, so to limit the effect do `{\tiny foo}` not `\tiny{foo}`. Alternatively in this case, use `ylabel style={font=\tiny}`.
- In two of your `\addplot`s you have `xticklabels`. This is wrong, that is a setting that belongs to the axis.
- Mostly recommended to use `\newcommand` over `\def` I think, so you don't accidentally overwrite existing macros.

[image: output of code below]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\definecolor{pythonGreen}{RGB}{0,128,0}


\tikzmath
{
  function symlog(\x,\a){
    \yLarge = ((\x>\a) - (\x<-\a)) * (ln(max(abs(\x/\a),1)) + 1);
    \ySmall = (\x >= -\a) * (\x <= \a) * \x / \a ;
    return \yLarge + \ySmall ;
  };
  function symexp(\y,\a){
    \xLarge = ((\y>1) - (\y<-1)) * \a * exp(abs(\y) - 1) ;
    \xSmall = (\y>=-1) * (\y<=1) * \a * \y ;
    return \xLarge + \xSmall ;
  };
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand\basis{1}
    \pgfplotsset
  {
    y coord trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{symlog(#1,\basis)}},
    y coord inv trafo/.code={\pgfmathparse{symexp(#1,\basis)}},
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,int detect,precision=2},
}

\pgfplotstableread{ % x, y1, y2, y_err1, y_err2
0 0.78 -1.03 0.21 1.07
1 -540 -1150 0.06 216
2 2.6 5.15 0.08 1.16
3 7.36 9.86 0.004 0.55
4 0.47 -0.03 0.75 0.76
5 -0.87 -0.87 0.99 1.06
6 0.10 -0.33 0.24 0.26
}\dataset

\begin{axis} [width=\linewidth,
    ybar = 0cm,
    bar width = 10pt,
    xtick = data,
    scaled ticks = base 10:0,
    ytick = {-10000, -1000, -100, -10, -1, 0, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000},
    scaled y ticks=false,
    minor ytick = {-9000, -8000, ..., -2000, -900, -800, ..., -200, -90, -80, ..., -20, -9, -8, ..., -2, -.9, -.8, ..., .9, 2, 3, ..., 9, 20, 30, ..., 90, 200, 300, ..., 900, 2000, 3000, ..., 9000},
    ymajorgrids,
    yminorgrids,
    xmajorgrids,
    xticklabels={A, B, C, D, E, F, G},
    x tick label style={rotate=90},
    ylabel={Y-Value},
    ylabel style={font=\tiny},
    tick label style={font=\tiny},
    legend style={nodes=right, font=\tiny}, 
    legend pos = south east
    ]
    
    
          
\addplot+[
    draw=black,
    fill=black!75,
    error bars/.cd,
        y dir=both,
        y explicit,
        error bar style={black}
   ]
        table[x index=0,
              y index=1,
              y error plus expr = {symlog(\thisrowno{1} + \thisrowno{3}, \basis) - symlog(\thisrowno{1}, \basis)},
              y error minus expr = {symlog(\thisrowno{1}, \basis) - symlog(\thisrowno{1} - \thisrowno{3}, \basis)}
              ] \dataset;

\addplot+[
    draw=black,
    fill=pythonGreen,
    error bars/.cd,
        y dir=both,
        y explicit,
        error bar style={black}
   ]
        table[x index=0,
              y index=1,
              y error plus expr = {symlog(\thisrowno{2} + \thisrowno{4}, \basis) - symlog(\thisrowno{2}, \basis)},
              y error minus expr = {symlog(\thisrowno{2},\basis)-symlog(\thisrowno{2}-\thisrowno{4},\basis)}
              ] \dataset;     



\legend {data1, data2};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you accidentally set the value for `y index` for  the second set of bars to 1 instead of 2 (the bars are now all the same length for data 1 and data 2), but this method works perfectly for me, thanks a lot!

Comment: @RVK Indeed I did, sorry about that.